# Использование noexcept

Tags: c++

Для чего используется noexcept в конструкторе перемещения? Насколько я понял, он используется, чтобы вызывать не конструктор перемещения, а копирующий конструктор. Верный ли мои рассуждения?

```
class String
{
    size_t len;
    char* buffer;
public:
    String(const char* str)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        buffer = new char[len + 1];
        memcpy(buffer, str, len + 1);

        std::cout << "Call CTR " << str << endl;


    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const String& str);
    ~String()
    {
        delete[] buffer;
    }

    String& operator= (const String& str)
    {
        delete[] buffer;
        if (this == &str)
        {
        }
        this->len = str.len;
        buffer = new char[len + 1];
        memcpy(buffer, str.buffer, len + 1);
        return *this;

        std::cout << "Call COPY " << str << endl;
    }

    char& operator[] (unsigned int index)
    {
        return buffer[index];
    }

    String(const String& str) 
        :
        len(str.len)
    {
        buffer = new char[len + 1];
        memcpy(buffer, str.buffer, len + 1);
    }

    String(const String&& str) noexcept
    {
    
        std::cout << "MOVE СTR\n" << str << endl;
    }

};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const String& str)
{
    stream << str.buffer;
    return stream;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    String str = "string";
    String str2 (std::move(str));
    return 0;
 }
```

Но если использовать либо нет `noexcept` все равно вызывается этот конструктор.

Comment: Вообще-то `noexcept` используется для того, чтоб указать, что вы гарантируете, что данная функция не генерирует исключения. Так что компилятор может просто уменьшить код, не пытаясь ничего перехватывать. Можете почитать это: https://habr.com/ru/post/164221/

Comment: @Harry Это понятно, но я читал в какой-то книге, что также будет вызван конструктор копирования, а не перемещения. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Очень странное утверждение. С чего бы?

Comment: Вы наверное имеете ввиду работу с контейнерами стандартной библиотеки. Там, если move-конструктор и move-оператор присваивания не помечены как `noexept`, то контейнер будет вызывать более медленные копирующие версии конструктора и оператора присваивания.

Comment: @DmitryK То есть, это работает только для STL?

Comment: Я бы сказал не "это работает только для STL", а так работают контейнеры из STL. Но они достаточно часто используются. Но и другие библиотеки могут также работать. А вообще `noexcept` помогает компилятору оптимизировать код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если move-ctor вашего класса не помечен как noexcept, действительно вместо него будет вызываться конструктор копирования, но в одном достаточно узком случае.

Допустим у вас есть вектор, в который вы добавляете объекты вашего класса. В какой-то момент вместимости вектора (размера выделенной под него памяти) перестает хватать и вектор делает переаллокацию - выделяет новую память с запасом и переносит туда содержимое старого фрагмента памяти. И если у вас кидающий перемещающий конструктор, вместо него вектор вызовет конструктор копирования.

Это сделано для того, чтобы сохранить состояние вектора в случае вылета исключения - если мы копировали объекты, можно просто почистить новую память и старое состояние вектора останется валидным, а в случае перемещения, непонятно, что куда возвращать.

Другие контейнеры стандартной библиотеки следуют тому же правилу

---

upd

Добавлю что наличие noexcept у методов позволяет компилятору лучше оптимизировать исполняемый файл (хотя к конструкторам копирования/перемещения это отношения не имеет).

Также cpp core guidelines рекомендуют всегда помечать move-ctor noexcept так как кидающий перемещающий конструктор "нарушает ожидания большинства людей": http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-move-noexcept

Comment: То есть, так работает только для STL? А если мне нужен схожий принцип, то я должен сам реализовать это? Я сначала думал, что так устроен компилятор, а не именно контейнеры

Comment: Я мало работал с другими библиотеками контейнеров, поэтому тут ничего не могу сказать. Если вы хотите написать свой вектор, то да, такое поведение вам придется реализовывать самостоятельно. Если вы пишете свой класс, который вы хотите помещать в стандартный вектор, то вам достаточно пометить move-ctor noexcept и стандартный вектор все сделает сам